# How can I empty Amarok's media collection?

Tags: amarok

Much to my dismay, Amarok defaulted to adding all audio files in my entire home folder to its local collection — without my permission.

The local collection is now full of uncurated garbage. How can I empty it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete `~/.kde/share/apps/amarok/mysqle`, as suggested in the [Amarok manual](http://userbase.kde.org/Amarok/Manual/Various/TroubleshootingAndCommonProblems#Database_issues):

> #### Database issues
>
> If the database is corrupt and this is preventing Amarok from starting, you can move the database to a backup location (or simply delete it). This will cause Amarok to rebuild the database from scratch. Move the `$HOME/.kde/share/apps/amarok/mysqle` folder to a backup location (such as `$HOME/.kde/share/apps/amarok/mysqle~`) and restart Amarok.

Comment: I must have a really bad error since even deleting the database, it fails to start properly (error at startup, no songs in local collection, no songs appear performing a rescan). Suggestions?